# how to generate source for selenium in java which is by default html

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium firefox addon for automation.I always see the script in HTML whether i create the test via recording or manually writting the script. Any idea what can be the best way to get the java source code, Please any one can help on this.

I tried the following many times, but no luck. Options-> Clipboard Format -> Java / jnuit4 / webdriver

Do i need to install some plugin or import some file etc? Can any body help me out ASAP.

Second thing, i also did this
File > Export test case as >  Java / jnuit4 / webdriver

The test case has been exported. and if i tried to opent that exported test case in selenium IDE then getting error "Error loading test case: no command found".

So i have 2 questions here
 1. how can i change the language from HTML to java in seelnium IDE?
 2. or if the solution of my first question is to export test case then why it is not opening in IDE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1. how can i change the language from HTML to java in seelnium IDE?**

You can export your selenese HTML code to any given language by using

File > Export test case as > Java / jnuit4 / webdriver(any other given language)

**2.if the solution of my first question is to export test case then why it is not opening in IDE?**

In Selenium IDE, You can open the test case which is in the HTML format (One you saved through Selenium IDE). In SIDE, It is not possible to open the exported test case which is in other formats like (.java, .py etc...).

Answer (score 0):

**1. how can i change the language from HTML to java in seelnium IDE?**

```
 1) Click on File a primary nav bar
 2) check drop down is displayed
 3) select on Export test case as 
 4) Check you can convert selenium test case in any language EG: Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver

Save File as .java
Your testcase is converted to WebDriver
```

[image]